# Flutter split a string keeping the delimeter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

How can I keep the delimiter when split using regex in flutter?

Text: `"this is {{A}} sample {{text}} ..."`

What I want is: `["this is", "{{A}}", "sample", "{{text}}", "..."]`

I've used the following regex,

`"this is {{A}} sample {{text}} ...".split(RegExp("{{(.*?)}}"))`

and got, `["this is ", " sample ", " ..."]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
(?={{)|(?<=}})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sgj0ZC/2)

Answer (score 2):

You might split using lookarounds with an alternation `|` to match both ways before and after the `{{...}}` part:

```
\s*(?={{.*?}})|(?<={{.*?}})\s*
```

The pattern matches:

- `\s*(?={{.*?}})` Match optional whitespace chars and assert directly to the right a pattern `{{...}}}`
- `|` Or
- `(?<={{.*?}})\s*` Assert a pattern `{{...}}}` to the left and match optional whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XLb8FJ/1) | [Dart demo](https://ideone.com/r5Vm9M#stdin)

```
void main() {
    var parts = "this is {{A}} sample {{text}} ...".split(RegExp("\\s*(?={{.*?}})|(?<={{.*?}})\\s*"));
    print(parts);
}
```

Output

```
[this is, {{A}}, sample, {{text}}, ...]
```

Comment: I quite like your answer, but have a problem with this: it is *not really* splitting the string on the delimiter (as asked by the OP): it misses the "white spaces" which are also part of the string and should be included. Is it possible to make some tweak to your pattern to get what OP asks for?

Comment: @Deczaloth if you want to keep the whiespaces, you can omit the `\s*` See https://regex101.com/r/SUHWwj/1

Comment: Very useful and flexible solution. Should be accepted and seen on top.

Answer (score 1):

An idea to get the result you are looking for, would be:

1. Split the string as you did,
2. find all matches,
3. insert the matches in your splitted string.

See the following sample that illustrates this idea:

```dart
void main() 
{
  String a = "this is {{A}} sample {{text}} ...";
  
  var allMatches = RegExp("{{(.*?)}}").allMatches(a);
  
  var parts = a.split(RegExp("{{(.*?)}}"));
  
  for(int i = 0; i < allMatches.length; i++) {

    int newIndex = 2*i+1;
    
    String? newDelimiter = allMatches.elementAt(i).group(0);
    
    
    if (newDelimiter!=null) {
      parts.insert(newIndex,newDelimiter);
    }
    
  }
    
  print(parts); // ["this is ", "{{A}}", " sample ", "{{text}}", " ..."]  
  
}
```

Comment: This will break if there is a string like this. "this is {{A}} sam{{ple {{text}} ..."